# Modifying Bonita Process Instance after Started

Tags: bonita

Is it possible to change the processinstance create/start date time after once it has been instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process Instance create/start date time automatically generated by system,
and also all bpm transaction (flow node, case, process, task,...) .

All engine APIs or apiAccess only have read access from the database.

But you can modify directly from database ;)